# How do I specify row heights in CSS Grid layout?

Tags: html, css, grid-layout, css-grid

I have a CSS Grid Layout in which I want to make **some** (middle 3) rows stretch to their maximum size. I'm probably looking for a property similar to what `flex-grow: 1` does with Flexbox but I can't seem to find a solution.

> Note: This is intended for an [Electron](http://electron.atom.io/) app only, so browser compatibility is not really a concern.

I have the following CSS Grid Layout:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1.5fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  height: calc(100vh - 10px);
}

.grid .box {
  background-color: grey;
}

.grid .box:first-child,
.grid .box:last-child {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: -1;
}

/* These rows should 'grow' to the max height available. */
.grid .box:nth-child(n+5):nth-child(-n+7) {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Which creates the following grid:

[image: Current Grid]

When none of the boxes contain any content I would like the grid to look something like this:

[image: Preferred Grid]

Comment: I should've stated that this is for an Electron app only so browser compatibility is not really a concern.

Comment: The Electron app I'm building has 1 view which is the grid like above. Since it's a grid I figured it would be fun to play around with the new CSS Grid Layout since it's (kinda) supported in Electron.

Comment: still new to CSS grid, fr unit is nice but indeed auto was the key to solve my issue as well

Answer (score 138, accepted):

One of the [Related posts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32314236/743512) gave me the (simple) answer.

Apparently the `auto` value on the `grid-template-rows` property does exactly what I was looking for.

```
.grid {
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1.5fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto auto 1fr 1fr 1fr auto auto;
    grid-gap:10px;
    height: calc(100vh - 10px);
}
```

Comment: What is the significance of `10px` in the `calc()` call?

Comment: @JohnKarahalis to compensate for the 10px `grid-gap` between the rows.

Comment: @DannyMeister that doesn't really make sense since the amount of rows is dynamic yet he only subtracts `10px`, which is equal to the gap between 2 rows.. 

Comment: Well I guess not compensation, but probably to make the upper and lower space around the grid be 5px which gives an even 5px (uncollapsed) margin around each row since grid-gap applies only in between elements in the grid. Reducing height by grid-gap or 2*grid-gap to taste seems fairly common in fullscreen applications I've seen. I prefer 2*grid-gap so whitespace around is same as inside.

Comment: This was actually the solution in my case, too. I had rows, that I wanted to hide (using `display: none`) and the space wouldn't collapse **even** with `display: none`set on those cells. Turns out I had to make sure to use `auto` on those particular rows and set the `height` in the cells themselves. Needless to say it worked exactly the way it was supposed to. Thank you!

Answer (score 21):

There is also the need to specify the minimum height for the elements, otherwise if they have no content they will disappear.

[image]

```css
:root{
  --body-margin:10px;
}
body{
  margin:var(--body-margin);
}
.grid {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1.5fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto 1fr 1fr 1fr auto auto;
  grid-gap:10px;
  height: calc(100vh - calc(2 * var(--body-margin)));
}
.grid div{
  min-height:20px;
  background-color: grey;
}
.grid 
  div:nth-child(n+5):nth-child(-n+7),
  div:first-child,
  div:last-child{
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

**Use of repeat with grid**

When boxes doesn't contain any content and If you want to get rid of the empty box spaces as well than you can use following.

```
grid-template-rows: repeat(2, auto) repeat(3, 1fr) repeat(2, auto);
```

Or more compact syntax as last two cell size will be by default auto if not defined:

```
grid-template-rows: repeat(2, auto) repeat(3, 1fr);
```

If you want some space in any case than you can use:

```
grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 10px) repeat(3, 1fr) repeat(2, 10px);
```

**Finally CSS would be**

```
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1.5fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, auto) repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  height: calc(100vh - 10px);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
.periodic-table {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(18, 60px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(7, 70px) 40px repeat(2, 70px);
  grid-gap: 2px;
}
```

This code will create 18 columns each of them are 60px, and 7 rows of 70px **8th row will be 40px** then again 9th and 10th row will be 70px.