# Make all items of same height and vertically centered with CSS grid

Tags: css, css-grid

With CSS grid, I know:

- how to make all items of same height (example 1 below)
- how to text items centered vertically (example 2)

**But how to make both at the same time: same height for all items (for example `1 fr`) and the text is vertically centered?**

I have already read [How do I specify row heights in CSS Grid layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41916722/how-do-i-specify-row-heights-in-css-grid-layout) and [Centering in CSS Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45536537/centering-in-css-grid), but here it seems specific to the `align-items: center;`.

Note: I would like to avoid mixing `grid` with `flexbox` or non-grid solutions like [How can I center text (horizontally and vertically) inside a div block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5703552/how-can-i-center-text-horizontally-and-vertically-inside-a-div-block).

See examples:

```css
.grid1 { display: grid; grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr); 
         grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr); grid-gap: 2em;  }
.grid2 { display: grid; grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr); 
         grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr); grid-gap: 2em; align-items: center; }
.item { background-color: yellow; }
```

```html
<div class="grid1">
<div class="item">
ABCABCABCABCABC
</div>
<div class="item">
DEFDEFDEFDEFDEF
</div>
<div class="item">
GHIGHIGHIGHIGHI
JKLJKLJKLJKLJKL
</div>
</div>
<br><br><br>
<div class="grid2">
<div class="item">
ABCABCABCABCABC
</div>
<div class="item">
DEFDEFDEFDEFDEF
</div>
<div class="item">
GHIGHIGHIGHIGHI
JKLJKLJKLJKLJKL
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: keep your first configuration and center the content inside the grid itemes using any classic method (flexbox, css grid, etc)

Comment: @TemaniAfif I wanted to avoid mixing my grid with Flexbox or CSS margins, do you have an idea?

Comment: There is nothing wrong *mixing* CSS features. You have 2 different requirements (1) make equal height [done] (2) center content inside div [check the duplicates for all the possible ways]